# Ruby on Rails Rendering tables with dynamic content and partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've used this site plenty of times to find my answer but im am unfortunately stuck now and need some help. On my main content page I am working on im running into an issue with creating a tables using CSS and div ids.

## Overview

The table is compromised of 2 rows and 6 columns and then spilt into 12 boxes which each box 200px X 200px. Now the content of each box contains a new item (@books) which is generated from a separate controller(used the built in generate scaffold command).  I am also using pagination to limit the items on the page (12) so older items just roll on back.

## Issue

I am able to populate each of the 12 boxes with new content by using the following code on my controller and view

controller

```
def content
@books= Book.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 12)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # content.html.erb
end
```

view {content.html.erb}

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <div id="column1">
      <tr>
        <td><%= book.name %></td>
        <td><%= book.title %></td>
        <td><%= book.content %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', book %></td>
     </tr>
  </div>
    <% end %>
<br />
<div id="paginate">
    <%= will_paginate(@books, 
) %)
</div>
</div>
```

What happens when I generate the view is that everything is rendering perfectly but all of my books are using the same 'column 1'

```
     <div id="column1">
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Content</td>

        <td><a href="/books/4d376fc63060da4abc000002">Show</a></td>
     </tr>
  </div>
  <div id="column1">
      <tr>
        <td>Title </td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Content</td>

        <td><a href="/books/4d3c96383060da31c9000001">Show</a></td>
     </tr>
  </div>
```

I would like for each book to have its own column {2, 3,4,...12} so i can target each individually if i need to using jquery. The other problem is that i would like to use render partial for everything in the  but when i use the render partial it places all the items within the 1 column {relisting of Book.all }so it just repeats all the contained information. I have a feeling im suppose to use another method or edit the current one to complete this but I'm unsure what goes were. Thanks!

greenz

## Update

Hey Mike i really appreciate your effort in trying to explain to a newby whats going on. I basically went back to step one a applied each piece of code to see where it is going bonkers at. You are doing a wonderful job explaining the issue yet i can't grasp whats going on when rendering the code because the ruby doc's for rendering and layout are pretty basic and dont have any examples where i can see how div_for tag effects the rendering process (I'm a visual person). I wanted to show you the new code but comments don't allow it so i opened an answer :(

The first edit was removing the

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
```

and replacing with

```
<table> 
   render @books
</table>
```

so now my code looks like this {content.html.erb}

```
<div id="maincontent">

    <table>
    render @books
    </table>
    <div id ="column1">
        <tr>
            <td><%= book.name %></td>
            <td><%= book.title %></td>
            <td><%= book.content %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', book %></td>
        </tr>

    </div>  
    <% end %>
    <br />

    <div id="paginate">

    <%= will_paginate(@books, 
    ) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

When this is applied i receive an unexpected end error when rendering the view pointing to the last line of my code.(When adding the end tag to the end it just threw another error) So i then changed the render page from _bookcontent.html.erb to _book.erb and inserted the partial between the column1 div as shown.

```
    <div id ="column1">

        <%= render :partial => "book" %>

    </div>
```

<% end %>

I understand what this tag is now doing it telling my partial that for every "book" render the latest book id from the database. So now the render @books statement is keeping track of the books id for every render page i insert. (I could be mistaken but this is how i perceive it). So now onto the infamous
_book.erb that this page is rendering here is my code.

```
<% div_for(book) do %>
<tr>
    <td><%= book.name %></td>
    <td><%= book.title %></td>
    <td><%= book.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', book %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

From my reading on the  <% div_for(book) do %> is wrapping a unique div id around each book such as

```
 <div id="book_123"> Book.name / Book.Title </div>
```

This div is now contained inside my column1 div ID from before which has all my styling for my column/boxes. From the lack of information on the div_for tag I am still running into errors and unexpected ends in my code. (Trying to debug the _book.erb with ruby -w doesn't work so i dont know how to use the end tags). These are the take aways i am trying to correct for my sanity.

1. Should I remove the `<div id="column1">` from my content page and apply a new div id / class elsewhere on my content page?
2. Where do i insert <% end %> tags one in the partial and in my content.html.erb before my pagination? It seems as though when i have both the renderer complains about unexpected ends at the end of each page.
3. When substituting your code in place of mines i receive the above unexpected end but this isn't due to you im definitely missing a component in my code.
4. I could be approaching this the wrong way from a layout perceptive in the first place but my main goal is to have 2 rows of 6 boxes/columns w/ each box containing a different book. Then using pagination to scroll back to the earlier books and apply the same layout which it does fine now but i am using the same column id for each book and need to target all the boxes separately.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, this is just a case of it doing what you said, not what you meant.

Whatever controller has the content method should look like this:

```
def content
  @books = Book.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 50
end
```

Your view should look like this(old syntax but still should work fine).

content.html.erb:

```
<div id="maincontent">
  <table>
    <%= render :partial => 'book', :collection => @books %>
  </table>
  <br />
  <%= will_paginate @books %>
</div>
```

Or try the new syntax. The new syntax is weird and I haven't tried it personally but I think this should work. So here is the alternate, more Rails 3 version of content.html.erb:

```
<div id="maincontent">
  <table>
    <%= render @books %>
  </table>
  <br />
  <%= will_paginate @books %>
</div>
```

I think it chooses the partial based on the class name and whether it is enumerable.

The _book.html.erb partial:

```
<%= div_for(book) do %>
<tr>
    <td><%= book.name %></td>
    <td><%= book.title %></td>
    <td><%= book.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', video %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

Div_for is the secret sauce.

The only end that is required is the one inside the partial to close the block opened when we called do after the div_for.

Comment: I fixed the code. I had forgotten the "do" at the end of the div_for statement. Notice that I have the table tag in the view and the div and tr tags will be created in the partial.

Answer (score 0):

```
Now i am getting unexpected end errors when i render the page here is my view

view = content.html.erb

    <div id="maincontent">

    render @books
      <div id="column1">
        <tr>
            <%= render :partial => "bookcontent" %>
        </tr>
      </div>
        <% end %>
    <br />
      <div id="paginate">
        <%= will_paginate(@books, 
        ) %>
      </div>
    </div>

Here is my render partial = _bookcontent.html.erb
   <% div_for(book) %>
<tr>
    <h3><%= book.name %></h3>
    <h3><%= book.title %></h3>
    <h3><%= book.content %></h3>
    <h3><%= link_to 'Show', book %></h3>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

I am also clueless as to if i should be using a div id or class. By default i always use just an id.

Comment: Part of Rails famous "convention over configuration" thing is that names are very significant. The name of the partial is going to be used as the name of the variable inside. _book means that a local variable "book" will be created inside the partial. You named the partial _bookcontent but are using the variable "book" without creating it. In the meantime Rails has created a var _bookcontent based on the name you used. Keep in mind you are passing a collection of Books(the model) and the partial will be rendered once for each book.

Comment: And FYI, generally you would edit your original question with additional details or just have some back and forth in the comments for this stuff rather than adding another answer to your own question. They really should let you put code in comments though.

Comment: Looks like you might have an orphaned 'end' after column 1 div closes.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Mike and Josh i have updated my question to reflect the changes.

Comment: Updated. Try that and let me know what happens. Apparently I've been using HAML long enough that I was forgetting how ERB works. :(

Comment: Div_for is the secret sauce Mike! Thanks for showing me how to use it properly. I never thought I would say this but that command is a sexy piece of code. Hey do you have any good tutorials on how to use HAML?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, your code is working fine but you want to have:

```
column1
column2
column3
...
```

for each book. If that is the case, why don't you simply replace:

```
 <div id="column1">
```

with

```
 <div id="column#{@book.id}">
```

or use a counter

```
<%
 book_counter=0
 @books.each do |book| 
 book_counter = book_counter+1
%>
  <div id="column#{book_counter.to_s}">
```